# Update a DataGridViewTable

Tags: vb.net

How do I make it possible for a user to select a row on a DataGridView table, be able to delete a row or edit? Also, how do I make the table update when I insert a row?

[image]

Here is the code:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Dim connect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Documents\School\CMPR105\Week 16\Opals Bedding.accdb")
        connect.Open()

        Dim deleteCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Delete from Sales", connect)

        deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        connect.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully deleted")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        Dim connect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Documents\School\CMPR105\Week 16\Opals Bedding.accdb")
        connect.Open()

        Dim updateCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update Sales set ID= '" & txtID.Text & "', ProductName = '" & txtName.Text & "', Price = '" & txtPrice.Text & "', Sold = '" & txtSold.Text & "', TotalSales = '" & txtSales.Text & "' ")

        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        connect.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
        Dim connect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Documents\School\CMPR105\Week 16\Opals Bedding.accdb")
        connect.Open()

        Dim insertCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Insert into Sales ([ID],[ProductName],[Price],[Sold],[TotalSales]) values ('" & txtID.Text & "', '" & txtName.Text & "', '" & txtPrice.Text & "','" & txtSold.Text & "', '" & txtSales.Text & "')", connect)

        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        connect.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Opals_BeddingDataSet2.Sales' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.SalesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Opals_BeddingDataSet2.Sales)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: VBA is not the same as VB.Net, hence I've removed the VBA tag.

Comment: Use an `OleDbDataAdapter` to populate a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid, preferably via a `BindingSource`. Any additions, modifications and deletions the user makes in the grid will be propagated to the `DataTable`. You then use the same data adapter to save all the changes back to the database in a batch.